# bluetooth not working on ubuntu 18.04 lenovo ideapad 330

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my Lenovo ideapad 330. My headphones connected but my Bluetooth wont switch on.

Any help is appreciated. I tried updating my kernel from 4.15 to 4.19 but it would not boot.

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5a02 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e500 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [17aa:3861]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[5] not in IVRS table
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: No southbridge IOAPIC found
[    0.028708] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, invalid threshold interrupt offset 1 for bank 4, block 0 (MSR00000413=0xd000000001000000)
[    0.050140] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.060486] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    1.901138] [drm] Found UVD firmware Version: 1.38 Family ID: 15
[    1.901466] [drm] Found VCE firmware Version: 52.0 Binary ID: 3
[   47.897120] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   47.897143] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   47.897147] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   47.897150] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   47.897156] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   48.256247] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   48.256267] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   48.256416] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin failed with error -2
[   48.281888] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 c3e0d04f
[   63.267554] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   63.267556] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   63.267561] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  109.948117] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  109.948128] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  109.948139] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  995.902087] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, invalid threshold interrupt offset 1 for bank 4, block 0 (MSR00000413=0xd000000001000000)
[ 2681.789949] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, invalid threshold interrupt offset 1 for bank 4, block 0 (MSR00000413=0xd000000001000000)
[ 3664.350548] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3680.222288] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3703.262411] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3719.133966] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4476.973952] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, invalid threshold interrupt offset 1 for bank 4, block 0 (MSR00000413=0xd0000000010000000
```

here is the next output you asked for

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12   MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.01 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0cf3 ProdID=e500 Rev= 0.01
C:* #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  16 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
I:* If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   0 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   0 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 1 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   9 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   9 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 2 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  17 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  17 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 3 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  25 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  25 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 4 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  33 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  33 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 5 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  49 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  49 Ivl=1ms
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: i ran that in the terminal but i don't know what any of this means. i am new to all of this. i added the output. hope i did it correctly.

Comment: File a bug report, start at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug and I will work on a temp fix

Comment: Please edit to also include results for `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | awk '/e500/' RS=`

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue with USB device 0cf3:e500 in the 4.15 kernel do in terminal

```
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/newbtfix-4.15.git
sudo dkms add ./newbtfix-4.15
sudo dkms install btusb/4.0
```

Check results for `mokutil --sb-state` if this replies Secure Boot is enabled, then you will need to enter UEFI/BIOS setting and disable Secure Boot
Reboot

Comment: this did not fix the bluetooth issue. still says device connected but won't connect.

Comment: Post URL for `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm' | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: http://termbin.com/o52mq

Comment: Do a complete shutdown, then boot

Comment: it still will not turn on

Comment: Post URL for `rfkill list | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: http://termbin.com/932w

Comment: What about `hciconfig -a | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: http://termbin.com/7i99

Comment: Try `bluetoothctl` followed by `power on` `scan on` and see if it finds anything